# Track localhost on Analytics in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, localhost, google-tag-manager

I have a problem with tracking Google Analytics on localhost with Google Tag Manager. I can see on the API for Analytics ( https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#localhost), all i need to do is to set cookieDomain to none. I do not find this option in Google Tag Manager. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation referenced it is about the Universal Analytics (new GA API version).

To solve this problem, you have two options:

**1)** Using the traditional tag "Google Analytics", in 'More settings' > 'Domains and Directories' > 'Domain Name':

```
none
```

**2)** Or switch to the "Universal Analytics" tag in Tag Google Manager, configure the required fields and in 'More settings' > 'Cookie Configuration' > 'Cookie Domain':

```
none
```

In both cases, this option should be **turned off** before the launch of the site.

Comment: We already upgraded to Universal. So, Fabio's solution 2) worked for us just fine.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201241/how-to-use-google-analytics-and-google-tag-manager-2-on-a-local-address/30204011#30204011 for how to set cookieDomain automatically based on hostname.

Comment: This solution is no longer workable. Google has removed the 'Cookie configuration' option from the UA tag. Cannot find another way at the moment.

Comment: It is still possible through the javascript API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#cookieDomain