# How can I test Google Tag manager locally

Tags: testing, localhost, google-tag-manager

I have created a GTM container, added tags under it and published.

its in debug mod and I can see datalayer

but for tags, says there are not tags in container

even though tags are there in container rules and tags

so question is, can I test gtm account on local machine even domain url of gtm is live.

if yes then why tags are not showing? does Google take time in publishing tags?

I tried google chrome plugin but it only shows basic info,

I want to work it like if I click on a product or do a purchase locally, it should update data for account remotely, is it possible?

Comment: You may find more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232276/track-localhost-on-analytics-in-google-tag-manager

Comment: Thank you, I will try this but I did it using vagrant share and used that url to test.

Comment: Perhaps using the [GTM Injector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-manager-injector/ooninanccdmjbcmghimhdfpeklpmlllg?hl=en-GB) extension for Chrome would work?

Comment: Links to screenshots are wrong.

Comment: screen cloud has deleted  screenshots.

Comment: Check that you don't using UBlock for tab with Tag manager

Answer (score 21):

Google Tag Manager can be easily tested on your local machine (no need for a Chrome extension), similar to how you would Preview your changes on a public website/app:

1. Setup your Google Tag Manager account.
2. Add the `<!-- Google Tag Manager -->` script to the `<head>` of your webpage(s).
3. Add the `<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->` to the `<body>` of your webpage(s) (optional).
4. Make the required updates in Google Tag Manager - e.g. add a new tag, etc.
5. Click Preview in Google Tag Manager.
6. Wait for the 'Now Previewing Workspace' banner to show in Google Tag Manager.
7. Start a local web server to run your app - this method will vary depending on your local setup but you should be able to access your app using a local URL like `localhost:8088/`.

   **NOTE:** Opening a file path (e.g. `file:///Users/your-name/Documents/`) in your browser ***WILL NOT*** work.
8. In the same browser as Google Tag Manager is open, open a new tab and go to your local web server URL - e.g `localhost:8088`.
9. The Google Tag Manager debug pane should be visible at the bottom of the browser window.

Comment: #8 fixed it for me thanks! Was testing different browsers

Comment: It's not working anymore, since the last GTM update.

Comment: man this sucks so much right now that its not working anymore...

Comment: If you are using an Adblocker, be sure to turn it off. That's what worked for me.

Comment: Disabling the "uBlock Origin" Chrome extension worked for me.

Comment: You now have to use https, which makes this a little more difficult.
I got it working easily with "http-server" (for npm). Note the TSL/SSL section: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server#tlsssl
(openssl is preinstalled on Mac/Linux, I think)

Comment: Ah, forgot: For me it also didn't work with a port in the address. So I had to configure it to use the stadard TLS port 443: "http-server -S -C cert.pem -p 443"

If you want to host a specific (sub-)directory: http-server my/dir -S -C cert.pem -p 443

Answer (score 6):

There's a minor update in the preview section.

1. Make sure you have a working setup of GTM
2. Open this URL https://tagassistant.google.com/
3. Click on add domain. This should open like the screenshot attached.
   [image]
4. Click on connect and this should open GTM in debug mode

Answer (score 5):

Just in case anyone hit the some issues I encountered.

With the new Tag Assistant

1. Set the url as localhost (will be `http://`, unless you have setup https locally)
   e.g. `http://localhost:8080/`
2. Disable any adblockers you have - this didn't cause me issues on our live website, but did on localhost

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to do anything different in local development to test it.

Just enable the debug/preview mode in the GTM Panel, then in the same browser you can access your website and there will be a console window at the bottom of the page, there you can see important info about the tags.

There's also a Google Chrome extension called `Tag Assistant` that you can use to debug the tags of the loaded page.

I know this is not a good practice but [this link](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/how-to-check-if-google-tag-manager-is-working/#gref) has many ways to verify that the tags are working alright.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [non-standard implementation](https://support.google.com/tagassistant/answer/3207128?hl=en#nonstandard) (e.g. using an Angular service to add the `<script>` tag), the GTM debugger may not work correctly. In my case while `localhost:4200` did load, the debugger would disconnect, the app would freeze, or the page would partially load.

In this scenario, revert to a standard implementation and reconnect the debugger.