# Enhanced Ecommerce data not showing up in Analytics using Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I am trying to implement Enhanced Ecommerce (EE) for Google Analytics (GA) using Google Tag Manager (GTM) but don't see any data showing up in GA.

Using the GTM preview mode, I can see that the data in the dataLayer is correct and that the right Tags are fired. I have also made sure to (correctly) create separate Tags for all the things I want to measure, which are:

- measuring the product detail view
- measuring the checkout process (both checkout steps and checkout options)
- measuring purchases

Perhaps I should also note that I am developing from localhost, but I don't think that should matter (?).

Edit:

When composing this question I was unable to post images, but I later realized I can post links of course. So, for clarification:

Tags that are fired on my Product Detail Page:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2woeqe8.jpg

The dataLayer containing the ecommerce data:
http://oi59.tinypic.com/6s7yxd.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out working localhost actually *was* the problem, my solution to this problem is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214212, but in short: go to `Tags` > `My Tags` > `Configure Tag` > `More Settings` > `Fields to Set`, type in 'cookie' in the `Field Name` input field, select `cookieDomain` from the suggestions, and set the value to `none`.